# Fluid in ARKit or SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, arkit

in one of the video of WWDC 21 I saw this spectacular image of a green fluid over the sofa

[image]

i can’t find to much tutorial online, How could be done this? I was looking into the particle system of SceneKit but looks like not doing exactly the same think( is more for smoke and fire) this fluid look more 3D.
what I should look for reproduce this fluid.. thanks Looking for some help to start my research.

Comment: could it be a geometry with a morpher applyed?

Comment: I don’t think so, because the final geometry is very random.. the morphed is more to transit from one define Geometry to Another…